# Midnight server went down, can decipher the logs

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, server-crashes

[image]Last night our main web server went down and in the course of 3 minutes the `syslog` went nuts.  I really am having a hard time deciphering whether the `syslog` is showing my symptoms of an underlying cause, or if there's information as to the **direct** cause.  Can anyone make heads or tails out of this?

First the fatal error messages:

```
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin systemd-udevd[513]: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 180 >/sys$DEVPATH/device/timeout'' failed with exit code 2.
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin systemd-udevd[513]: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 180 >/sys$DEVPATH/device/timeout'' failed with exit code 2.
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin systemd-udevd[505]: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 180 >/sys$DEVPATH/device/timeout'' failed with exit code 2.
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin systemd-udevd[514]: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 180 >/sys$DEVPATH/device/timeout'' failed with exit code 2.
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin systemd-udevd[508]: Process '/bin/sh -c 'echo 180 >/sys$DEVPATH/device/timeout'' failed with exit code 2.
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin rpcbind[856]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr: failed
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin rpcbind[856]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr: failed

Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin kernel: [    0.436467] pci 0000:00:17.4: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin kernel: [    0.431044] pci 0000:00:15.3: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
-------------^^^ THIS ONE HAPPENED ABOUT 20 TIME


Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin kernel: [    2.499847] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin kernel: [    2.500273] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
Jun 15 23:27:04 ywpadmin kernel: [    5.933471] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jun 15 23:27:05 ywpadmin sm-mta[1254]: gethostbyaddr(10.2.x.x) failed: 1
```

I am attaching the full log for those few minutes..  It's extensive, but that's why I put the fatal errors first.  This is the beginning of "abnormalcy" in the logs right up until I forced a server reboot:

[SYSLOG](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/dcvRHT1ygZ)

I am thouroughly confused by this .. All it is, is a basic webserver ...  It is worth mentioning that accidentally the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` was baing "tailed" `tail -f error.log` for an extended period of time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a physical or virtual server? And what OS version? If virtual what Hyper-visor and version?

Comment: The server is a VMware ESXI virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 OS.  4 cores, 8GB memory.  Minion graphs donut indicate any strange CPU spikes or RAM spikes either

Comment: Munin -- Apologies

Comment: It looks to me like you just ran out of disk (you're in vmware, every device, file, etc is sharing the same virtual device, thus the error messages frorm your *floppy* drive as it goes burning down....)    Your syslog is a regular noisy boot inside esxi, nothing looks unusal to me.

Comment: Is this a VMWARE issue or a Virtual Machine (virtual disk) issue?  when I did the df -h command it shows 48% used on main disk, and over 50% free?

Comment: I added an image .. This look to be less than a "normal" noisy boot ..